# Is it acceptable to request the future employer to extend my internship duration?

Tags: internship, negotiation

I got an offer for an internship from a company who I've interviewed with before. I even restated during my interview and my application that I requested for a 6 months internship program, but they offering me for 3 months only.

Is it acceptable to ask them about why they are decided to cut short my internship duration and requested for longer duration as possible?

Comment: Are you required to do a 6 months internship (eg. your school wants it) ?

Comment: No, I'm applying an internship independently to that particular company because they have specific skills and technologies I would like to get my hands on.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably a probation period. Get your foot in the door first and after two months as for an extension - or perhaps full time employment.

Comment: So is it appropriate though to ask them?

Comment: Get two months under your belt - then ask them

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable to ask them about why they are decided to cut short my internship duration and requested for longer duration as possible?

It's an offer, until you accept it everything is open to negotiation. But interns are not usually very highly valued, so you may end up with the offer being withdrawn if you keep pushing the point. You have asked twice already and been disregarded.